# Check transitive dependencies for a maven .jar file

Tags: maven, maven-3

I need to write a java program to check if a given .jar file include a dependency (both direct and transitive). If the file include the dependency, return true. Otherwise return false.

Basically, the company has a list of outdated and vulnerable dependencies that it doesn't want the employee to include in their .jar files uto be executed in the cloud.

Direct dependency is simple. I only need to find all pom.xml files in the .jar file and check the groupId, artifactId and version.

However, transitive dependency is the tricky one.

I tried `mvn dependency:tree` in the terminal. That prints out the dependency tree pretty nicely (I assume it also considered all the  tag in the .xml. When I tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mvn dependency:tree")` in the java code, it does not seem to work. Is there any way to have the java program run this code (i.e `mvn dependency:tree`), store the dependency tree and check in the java program if this file include that dependency?

If there's any other way/api/package that is easier to do this, please also let me know. All help is appreciated.

Edit:
Thank you all for the help so far! The product I am working on is a data development platform, which uses Maven on its backend. The user is allowed to upload their .jar file to be executed on cloud (how they run, Idk, that's another department's work. We are kind of between the server and the frontend). Users write their .jar file on their own. Once they are done writing it, they will upload it to the cloud for big data execution. But the cloud has already have some dependency to keep it running. In case the new .jar file have conflict with the existing dependency which the cloud is using (also for security reason), we need to pre-check the .jar file before allowing it to be uploaded. So I am using maven model (MavenXpp3Reader) to read and check direct dependency in the pom.xml (i.e stuff like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

), which is easy to do.

But let's say this dependency has a transitive vulnerable dependency log4j-core:2.7, which is also in the block list, we will not allow the jar file to be uploaded (will not open the upload port) and show user a warning that their .jar file has dependency that is on the block list.

Hope this makes sense. Is it possible to achieve this at all?

Comment: In general a jar file does not contain transitive nor dependencies only so called fat jar's do that.. If you want to prevent to add a dependency which is not allowed you should check https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/ which can simply prevent adding a not allowed dependency and break your build.... (https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) much easier ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the user wrote their code and build the .jar file. I don't have control over what they build or include. I just need to check the .jar file before allowing the file to be uploaded.

Comment: I think you need the Maven Resolver library. There, you can probably load the `pom.xml` from the JAR and resolve the transitive dependencies.

Comment: @khmarbaise Maybe you can provide some example code for this? This should be done somewhere in Maven as well, i.e. download a JAR with a POM, and then resolve all transitive dependencies of that POM.

Comment: Can you explain that: `I just need to check the .jar file before allowing the file to be uploaded.`. more in detail?

Comment: @J Fabian Meier Can you give an example of on how to use Maven Resolver library please? I tried messing around with it for quite some time now, but no luck 